# Describe $\mathbb{Z}[\omega] / (2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

$$\Bbb Z[ω] = \{\;a + bω: a, b\in\Bbb Z\;\}\;,\;\; ω = e^{2πi / 3} = -\frac12 +\frac{\sqrt3}2i$$

Describe $\;\Bbb Z[ω]/(2)\;$ where $\;(2)\;$ is an ideal.
I already described it as a ring, and am now looking to describe it as:

x̅<sub>1</sub>, ..., x̅<sub>r</sub> for some specific x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>r</sub> where x̅<sub>i</sub> are in the ideal.

Comment: WE suspect it, but it'd be great if you'd tell us what is $\;\omega\;$ instead that we'd use our crystal balls to guess it. The same goes for $\;\overline{x_i}\;$ and etc.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry about that.

Comment: Do you know $\;\Bbb Z[\omega]\cong\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\;$ as groups?

Comment: I do not know that

Comment: Ok, where does this question come from? Are you studying algebraic number theory, or fields extensions? You're asking about a quotient ring of a very specific ring by a very specific (principal) ideal.

Comment: I am studying algebraic number theory.  We were just introduced to the Eisenstein integers in this assignment.  I have experience with Rings Modulo Ideals working with the Gaussian integers already.

Comment: The $\bar x_i$  are in which ideal?

Comment: And if you know that the Eisenstein integers are a Principal Ideal Domain, thus have unique factorization, you can use the fact that $2$ is a prime there and get a good result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $2$ and $2\omega$ are both in the ideal $(2)$. This means you can reduce any element $a+b\omega$ to one of these equivalence classes: $$\{0, 1, \omega, 1+\omega\}.$$ Now you can describe the ring structure by writing out a table for addition and a table for multiplication (keeping in mind that $1+1 = 0$ and $\omega^2 = \omega + 1$).

There aren't so many possibilities though; for instance, the multiplicative group of nonzero elements can only be a cyclic group of order three.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is what you expect, but your question isn't very clear.

As $\mathbf Z[\omega]\simeq \mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ we have:
$$\mathbf Z[\omega]/(2)\simeq \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+x+1)$$
The polynomial $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z=\mathbf F_2$, hence this quotient is a quadratic extension of $\mathbf F_2$ (there's only, up to isomorphism), i.e. it is isomorphic to $\mathbf F_4$.